# Sencha Touch 2 - "change" event listener for textfield

Tags: javascript, dom-events, sencha-touch-2

I would like to add an event listener for the change event on a textfield. I created a view which contains a form panel - everything works so far.

Now I tried to add a event listener to one of the textfields:

```
  items:[
        {
            xtype    :"textfield",
            name     :"field",
            label    :"field",
            required :true,
            listeners:{
                change:{
                    fn    : "onChangeHandler",
                    scope: this
                },
            }
    },
```

But it doesn't really work .. nothing happens. No errors and no function call. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Tried another thing - directly within the item definition:

```
    {
    xtype    :"textfield",
    name     :"field",
    label    :"field",
    required :true,
    listeners:{
        change:{
            fn    :this.onChange
        },
        scope :this
    }
},
```

But then on change I got this error on console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
listeners:{
                        change:{
                            fn    : "onChangeHandler",
                            scope: this
                        },
                    }
```

to this:

```
listeners:{
                        change: this.onChangeHandler
                    }
```

**Updated:**
The most simple way is to set an id for your `app.view.Login` (say 'abc'), then:

```
fn: function() {Ext.getCmp('abc').onEvent();},
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. Nothing happens ... I tried another thing, see my edit in post.

Comment: do you use controller in your app? If yes, it's easier to solve your problem

Comment: No, not for that view. But why is it so tricky to create a form panel with some elements as a view and define some event listeners within? I don't know why it's not working .. I have seen some examples with the listener definitions on an item and the handlers within the view. But this solution is only producing the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined ".

Comment: please fiddle your source code, I'm not sure whether what you've posted is really the reason or not ...

Comment: Okay, here are the links: http://www.senchafiddle.com/full/!Rk1l0/ http://www.senchafiddle.com/#Rk1l0 .. I minimized it a bit and, but the errors are the same. You can see my different attempts.

Comment: please try out my updated answer, I'm quite sure it's the easiest way without using any controller

Answer (score 2):

I think there's some sort of scoping issue with 'this'.  You might be better off handling events in a controller.  Add an id to your username textfield (id: 'username',)then try using my controller.  I get callbacks for the keyup and tap events; I'm getting some sort of error after the *change* callback but it does fire.  Also, you had the event name wrong for keyup.  Sencha lists all their [events](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Text) for each object, which I've find quite helpful.

[image]

LoginController

```
Ext.define("App.controller.LoginController", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",

    config: {
        refs: {
            username: '#username'
        },
        control: {
            username: {
                keyup: 'onUsernameKeyUp',
                change: 'onUsernameChange'
            }
        }
    },
    onUsernameKeyUp: function() {
        console.log("onUsernameKeyUp");
    },
    onUsernameChange: function() {
        console.log("onUsernameChange");
    },
    launch: function () {
        this.callParent();
        console.log("launch");
    },
    init: function () {
        this.callParent();
        console.log("init");
    }
});
```

app.js - Added controllers: []

```
Ext.application({
    name:'App',

    controllers: ['LoginController'],
    phoneStartupScreen :'resources/loading/Homescreen.jpg',
    tabletStartupScreen:'resources/loading/Homescreen~ipad.jpg',

    launch:function () {
        var loginform = Ext.create("App.view.Login");

        Ext.Viewport.add([loginform]);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put "scope" into "change" block.

```
listeners:{
  change:{
    fn    :this.onChange,
    scope :this
  }
}
```

You have error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined`
because you've written:

```
listeners:{
  change:{
    fn    :this.onChange
    },
    scope :this
}
```

Do you see the difference? :)

Also check that you put listener into "config" block and function "onChange" after "config" block.

Comment: I've tried both, but nothing worked. Do you tried it within sencha fiddle?